# Disallow iOS version updates on iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, appletv

Is there a way, with like a .mobileconfig profile or else, to disallow update of iOS version on a device? OTA or cable.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable OTA updates by installing the Apple TV beta profile on your iOS device. If you are an Apple Developer you can obtain the beta profile from the Downloads section. Installing this profile changes the software update catalog location to the one used for Apple TV updates, and therefore iOS reads the catalog and finds no updates suitable for iOS.

If your device is jailbroken, you can install [NO PLS RECOVERY](https://cydia.angelxwind.net/?page/net.angelxwind.noplsrecovery) which prevents your device from entering recovery mode initiated by iTunes, preventing iTunes from updating the device.

It's not possible to prevent someone with physical access to the device from entering DFU using the buttons on the device and restoring iOS.

Comment: This is what Google told me too, so yes it would be a workaround. Or putting in another way, no there is no officially supported way to do it, not even with profiles (I had a look).